# Varieties corresponding to closure of a function field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be a variety over a field $k$, and let $k(V)$ be its function field.

Let $\overline{k(V)}$ be a separable algebraic closure of $k(V)$, and let $\overline{V}$ be a variety (in the birational equivalence class) whose function field is $\overline{k(V)}$.

Provided it makes sense to talk about $\overline{V}$ (what is its field of definition?), what is the geometrical relationship of $\overline{V}$ to $V$? Is it related to  some "universal cover" of $V$?

Comment: The "what is its field of definition" seems to be the main issue, to start with.

Comment: The problem is that $\overline{k(V)}$ is not usually finitely generated over, say, $\overline{k}$ (think about $\mathbb{C}(x)$). So it wouldn't be the function field of a variety defined over $\overline{k}$.